# How to read packets with VLAN layer

Tags: python, wireshark, pcap, vlan

I'm writing a program in Python to read and decode GOOSE packets from a .pcap file. So far, I've been able to read the packets with the Pypcapfile library:

```
from pcapfile import savefile
file = input("Enter the name of the pcap file: ")
try:
    pcap = open(file, 'rb')
except IOError:
    print("No file with name \"{}\" was found.\n".format(file))
    return
capfile = savefile.load_savefile(pcap, verbose=True)
print(capfile)
```

Terminal:

```
Enter the name of the pcap file: goose2.pcap
[+] attempting to load goose2.pcap
[+] found valid header
[+] loaded 8023 packets
[+] finished loading savefile.
b'little'-endian capture file version 2.4
microsecond time resolution
snapshot length: 262144
linklayer type: LINKTYPE_ETHERNET
number of packets: 8023
```

The problem is that when I test my code with packets that contain a VLAN header (a mere two bytes), it says that the pcap file has 0 packets:

```
Enter the name of the pcap file: vlan.pcap
[+] attempting to load vlan.pcap
[+] found valid header
[+] loaded 0 packets
[+] finished loading savefile.
b'big'-endian capture file version 2.4
nanosecond time resolution
snapshot length: 65535
linklayer type: LINKTYPE_ETHERNET
number of packets: 0
```

I wrote my whole code around the Pypcapfile library so I want to avoid starting from the beginning with another library such as Scapy. I already tried adding the "layers=" argument to load_savefile but that didn't work. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Do you have any sample data you can post somewhere?

Comment: I was able to anonymize goose2.pcap but not vlan.pcap. If that would still be helpful, where should I post it?

Comment: I grabbed `vlanp.cap.gz` from the WireShark [Sample Captures](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures) page, and I can't reproduce your problem: The `pcapfile` module seems to read the file just fine. If you can reproduce your problem using that sample file, that would make it easier to diagnose.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't even able to open the file with load_savefile (unknown magic number) but after I renamed the extension to .pcap it read fine - number of packets: 395. I notice that print(capfile) output b'little'-endian just like with goose2.pcap, whereas with vlan.pcap it output b'big'-endian.

Comment: Note that `vlan.cap.gz` is gzip compressed; you would need to decompress it (`gunzip vlan.cap.gz`) before trying to open it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I've tested things on my end. I grabbed the sample vlan capture from the wireshark wiki and decompressed it:

```
$ curl -o vlan.cap.gz 'https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=vlan.cap.gz'
$ gunzip vlan.cap.gz
```

We can use e.g. `tshark` to verify that this capture includes VLAN tagged packets:

```
$ tshark -r vlan.cap -V
Frame 1: 1518 bytes on wire (12144 bits), 1518 bytes captured (12144 bits)
[...]
Ethernet II, Src: AniCommu_40:ef:24 (00:40:05:40:ef:24), Dst: 3com_9f:b1:f3 (00:60:08:9f:b1:f3)
[...]
    Type: 802.1Q Virtual LAN (0x8100)
802.1Q Virtual LAN, PRI: 0, DEI: 0, ID: 32
    000. .... .... .... = Priority: Best Effort (default) (0)
    ...0 .... .... .... = DEI: Ineligible
    .... 0000 0010 0000 = ID: 32
    Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 131.151.32.129, Dst: 131.151.32.21
```

I can open this use the `pcapfile` module:

```
$ pip install --user Pypcapfile
$ python
>>> import pcapfile.savefile
>>> with open('vlan.cap', 'rb') as fd:
...   capfile = pcapfile.savefile.load_savefile(fd, layers=2)
...
>>> capfile
b'little'-endian capture file version 2.4
microsecond time resolution
snapshot length: 65535
linklayer type: LINKTYPE_ETHERNET
number of packets: 395
>>> capfile.packets[0]
ethernet from b'00:40:05:40:ef:24' to b'00:60:08:9f:b1:f3' type unknown
```

But it looks like `pcapfile` doesn't have a particular decoder for VLAN frames.

---

The `dpkt` module works great:

```
>>> import dpkt
>>> fd = open('vlan.cap', 'rb')
>>> capfile = dpkt.pcap.Reader(fd)
>>> ts, buf = next(capfile)
>>> pkt = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
>>> pkt.vlan_tags
[VLANtag8021Q(pri=0, cfi=0, id=32)]
```

As does `scapy`:

```
>>> import scapy.all
>>> capfile = scapy.all.rdpcap('vlan.cap')
>>> capfile[0].vlan
32
```

Comment: Awesome, I will try to integrate this into my code. Thank you very much for the help!